# Unable to find/install the Java package acm.graphics

Tags: java, package, acm.graphics

I get the following error message

```
RobotFace.java:3: package acm.graphics does not exist
import acm.graphics.*; 
^
```

It suggests me that I do not have acm.graphics -package.

I have tried to find and install the package in MacPorts unsuccessfully by

```
port search acm
```

**How can you install acm.graphics package** in your computer for Java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the answer below, you need the acm.jar file. Here's how to do it in 3 easy steps:
1. Under "downloads", download the acm.jar file here: [Stanford's website](http://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/jtf/).
2. See screenshots below.  I'm using NetBeans for my IDE, but it should be more or less the same for any IDE.  I right-clicked "libraries" and added the acm.jar file. (Note from screenshots: I took these screenshots after I installed the acm.jar file.  You won't see this in your libraries folder until after you have completed this procedure.)
3. Refresh your project.

[image: Libraries folder]

[image: Right-clicked]

Answer (score 4):

A quick Google search yielded http://jtf.acm.org/.

Note there is a "acm.jar" file. You need to download that and add it to your CLASSPATH.

Comment: How can you put the folder to your CLASSPATH? I put the code unsuccessfully to my .bashrc: export CLASSPATH='$CLASSPATH:/Users/cs/Documents/acm:' . I get the same error as previously.

Comment: You need to add the JAR file to your classpath, not the folder, although technically you can add the folder in Java v6+ using a wildcard "*" char, e.g /usr/local/users/jarfiles/*, which will glob every JAR file in that directory. Since the JAR file is an archive file that contains multiple inner class, manifest and other files, that file added to the classpath will be searched for referenced classes.